# CSS Two-Column Layout Positioning Alignment

Tags: html, css

[image]

Using CSS, I'm looking to create something like this.  I want the signature to align with the bottom of the other boxes as shown in the picture.  However, either box should be able to have more content than the other and the signature should align with the lowest of the two.  In other words, if a post and signature are really short but awards are really long, there should be blank space in between the post text and the signature to align it with the bottom of the author/award box.  However, if the post box is longer, the author/award box will scale accordingly, but the signature will just sit below the post text with little to no blank space.

I've tried using absolute positioning with a 0 bottom margin on the signature, but it overlaps the post text.  I've tried vertical-align, but that doesn't work either.  There's two things I haven't tried because I have no idea how to do them: 1) using absolute positioning on the signature, but creating a blank element of the same size that remains in the document flow to emulate the signature remaining in the document flow.  This could potentially cause other problems since I haven't been able to see what it'd look like.  2) Using simple blank space in the document flow beneath the post text enough to push the signature down to the bottom of the author/award box (or 0 height, if the post text is longer than the awards).

Does anybody have any ideas?

Here's what I have now

```
<div class="tborder {$altbg}" style="{$post_extra_style} {$post_visibility} width: auto;" id="post_{$post['pid']}">



<div style="overflow:hidden; border-collapse: collapse; position: relative;">

<div class="post_left" style="width: 19%;">


<div class="post_user" style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.25em; min-height:50px">
<span style="vertical-align: middle;"><strong>{$post['profilelink']}</strong></span>
</div>
<div class="post_userbit" style="width: 100%; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; >{$post['useravatar']}<br />
{$post['groupimage']}
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 0.5em; padding-bottom: 0.5em;"><strong>
<span class="medtext">
{$post['userstars']}
{$post['usertitle']}<br />
{$post['user_details']}
</strong>
</div>
<div class="post_awards" style="width: 189px; margin: 0 auto;">
{$post['myawards']}<br />
</div>
</span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="post_right" style="width: 78%; align: right; height: 100%;">


<div class="post_meta" style="min-height:50px">
<span class="smalltext">{$post['postdate']} {$post['posttime']}</span>
{$post['posturl']}
</div>
<div id="pid_{$post['pid']}" class="post_body;">
{$post['message']}
</div>

<table align="left" width="78%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="postbit_signature" style="bottom: 0;">

            <tr valign="bottom">
                <td align="left">{$post['attachments']}{$post['signature']}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both"></div>



<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="postbit_buttons">

            <tr valign="bottom">
                <td align="left"><span class="smalltext">{$post['button_email']}{$post['button_pm']}{$post['button_www']}{$post['button_find']}{$post['button_rep']}</span></td>
                <td align="right">{$post['button_tyl']}{$post['button_edit']}{$post['button_quickdelete']}{$post['button_multiquote']}{$post['button_warn']}{$post['button_reply_pm']}{$post['button_replyall_pm']}{$post['button_report']}{$post['button_forward_pm']}{$post['button_delete_pm']}{$post['button_quote']}
</td>
            </tr>
        </table>





</div>
```

And here's what it's doing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/48wEo.png

Comment: Just put everything in a `<table>`. it will give you more control. Your required output will also be rendered easily.

Comment: Add your code or provide a jsfiddle

Comment: Code added, along with a screenshot showing what it's doing now and where the signature should be positioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PLEASE TRY THIS...

<!-- CSS -->

*{box-sizing:border-box;}
#table{display:table;width:100%;}
#table ul{display:table-row;}
#table ul li{display:table-cell;width:20%;border:2px solid #ccc;padding:10px;}
#table ul li+li{width:80%;position:relative;}

#signature{position:absolute;left:10px;bottom:10px;} /* left and bottom should be equal to left and bottom padding of parent element for proper alignment */
#dummy-signature{visibility:hidden;margin:15px;}


<!-- HTML -->

<div id="table">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
        </li>


        <li>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

            <div id="signature">Signature</div>
            <div id="dummy-signature">Signatureeee</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following CSS table structure:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-col abc">
            <p>
                This is test paragraph. 
                This is test paragraph. 
                This is test paragraph.
                This is test paragraph.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-col xyz">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table { 
    display: table; 
    width: 100%; 
    border-collapse:separate; 
    border-spacing:5px; 
}

.table-row{ display: table-row; }

.table-col { 
    display: table-cell;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
}

.left { width: 20%; }
.right { width: 80%; }
```

**[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tx3kz/)**